# Модификация Observable при помощи дополнительного запроса в сеть

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

работаю с Vk.APi и произвожу поиск списка групп.

В ответе с API получаю список групп, но проблема в том, что каждая из них не содержит количество участников, поэтому мне приходиться для каждой группы производить повторный запрос к API, чтобы получить список участников для каждой группы.

И я столкнулся с проблемой - не знаю, как правильно преобразовать список полученных групп.

Прошу вашей помощи.

Интерфейс для обращения к API:

```
interface GroupApi {

    @GET(ApiMethods.SEARCH_GROUPS)
    fun getGroups(@QueryMap map: Map<String, String?>) : Observable<GroupResponse<Group>>

    @GET(ApiMethods.SEARCH_MEMBERS_INFO)
    fun getMembersIds(@QueryMap map: Map<String, String?>) : Observable<GroupResponse<String>>
}
```

Классы получаемой модели:

```
data class GroupResponse<T>(
        @SerializedName("response")
        @Expose
        val response: Response<T>?
)

data class Response<T>(
        val count: Int,
        val items: List<T>
)
```

Класс `Group` довольно большой, главное, что в нем есть поле `membersCount`, которое необходимо заполнить

Rx code:

```
private fun test(q: String): Observable<List<Group>> {
         interactor?.let {
             it.getGroupList(q)
                    .flatMap { groupResponse: GroupResponse<Group> -> Observable.just(groupResponse.response?.items) }
                    .flatMap { groupList: List<Group> -> Observable.fromIterable(groupList) }
                    .flatMap { group: Group ->
                        Observable.zip(Observable.just(group), interactor?.let { it.getGroupMembersInfo(group.id.toString()) },
                                BiFunction { group: Group, groupMembersResponse: GroupResponse<String> ->  {
                                    group.membersCount = groupMembersResponse.response?.count.toString()
                                }})
                    }
        }
        //how should I return data ?
    }
```

К тому же, кажется, мой код почему то очень странно работает. список групп достать получается, а вот уже дополнительный запрос не отрабатывает.

Может быть я еще с `flatMap` намудрил чего ?